# Laravel's Artisan says nothing to migrate

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I installed migrations with `php artisan migrate:install` then created a migration with the `php artisan migrate:make create_teams_table` command. Now I try to run them with the following command that I made according to the [official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations):

```
php artisan migrate --path=app/foo/migrations/2014_01_21_143531_create_teams_table.php
```

This gives me the following on the console:

> Nothing to migrate.

The `migrations` table in the database is empty and the new table isn't created neither. I don't understand why the documentation says `foo` in the path. What does `foo` mean and where does it comes from? First I tought that the path is wrong because of the `foo` thing and as I know the path is relative to the `app` folder so I changed it to `app/database/migrations` but it doesn't work. I also tried a lot of other path combination but none of them worked.

Did I entered the wrong path? In this case shouldn't the console show some other kind of helpfull message? What does `foo` mean? How can I run my migration?

Comment: if you keep your migrations in `app/database/migrations`, you should be able to ignore the path parameter entirely

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That `foo` thing is just an example. Laravel will look for migrations to run in `app/database/migrations` on default. Try removing that `--path` parameter and see if it works.

Comment: Shouldn't that run all the migrations? I need to run only the last one because the project has a lot of older ones that are now wrong.

Comment: The thing about migrations is that they are supposed to work as a batch. You should be able to run `php artisan migrate:refresh` without any troubles. So with that in mind, I would say remove/move those broken ones and keep the nice ones.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that I mixed up the chapters in the documentation. I tought I can run a specific migration by passing the path, but it was actually the migration creation example. What a fail.

Comment: @AntonNiklasson That command will most definitely give you troubles on a production DB, unless your definition of trouble somehow doesn't include dropping all your live data.

Answer (score 63):

Try this:

First:

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```

Rolled back: `2014_03_28_142140_user_table`

Nothing to rollback.

second:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Migrated: `2014_03_28_142140_user_table`

check the database.

Comment: If there's existing data and you don't want to lose it just make export it first (backup).

Answer (score 18):

**You don't need to move the migration file anywhere**, just change its filename; for example, increase time integer and then run the `migrate` command with the path pointing to the migration. e.g: `php artisan migrate --path="database/migrations/2019_07_06_145857_create_products_table.php"`

Comment: Yes, This Correct Answer. Worked for me. Already that file is cached, that's why its not working.

Answer (score 11):

What helped me:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 11):

need to delete 2014_01_21_143531_create_teams_table of migrations table.

1. go to database(phpmyadmin)
2. open your database name.
   3.open migrations table.
3. delete the 2014_01_21_143531_create_teams_table row

Comment: This is the correct answer, when working on a running system, that can't just reset the complete database!

Comment: Best way to alter table and migrate it on servers when it says `nothing to migrate`

Answer (score 10):

The path argument is for creating a migration for example:

```
 php artisan migrate:make create_user_table --path=app/database/migrations/user_migrations/
```

But it is not documented to use while running the migrations, as it was in prior versions of laravel.

Dropping the --path argument should work in your case

Comment: This is quite similar with what is tried in the example.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who still cannot migrate their database:

Assume you have a file to migrate `abc_migrate.php`.

Firstly put your file inside the new folder named `abc_folder`.
Then, enter this command 
`php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/abc_folder/`.

You don't have to add file name at last of the directory path.

Done. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

use

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

it would refresh your database and run your all migrations again

**Note:**, don't do this in production, it will wipe your all your data. so before running this command do have a backup of your data. in fact, have backup data whenever you are touching database in production.

Comment: This was the only thing that helped me!!

Answer (score 1):

At least in Laravel 7, you have to add ".php" at the end of the name of the migration.

Example:

```
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/yyyy_mm_dd_table_name.php
```

Hope this answer help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is refresh the migration

```
    php artisan migrate:refresh --path=app/foo/migrations/2014_01_21_143531_create_teams_table.php
```

Comment: As of laravel 9 this refreshes other migrations as well. Not a good idea, this command.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is the filename for the migration is cached, and so even though you are changing the migration file, it is not seeing any changes, and so thinks there is nothing to migrate.

There's two ways to fix this:

You can change the file name slightly from from `2014_01_21_143531_create_teams_table.php` to `2014_01_21_143532_create_teams_table.php` (incrementing the number by 1) and then run `php artisan migrate...`

or

You can run `php artisan optimize:clear` to flush the cache and then run `php artisan migrate:fresh` to do a fresh migration.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises if the `migrations` table in the database is empty.
So the solution is open up the tinker from the composer

```
$ php artisan tinker
>>> Schema::drop('users')
>>> Schema::drop('password_resets')
>>> Schema::drop('orders')
>>> exit
php artisan migrate
```

Here is the result of the above commands executed

```
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$ php artisan migrate
```

> In Connection.php line 647:
>                                                                                     SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users'
>   alre     ady exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not
>   null auto_incr     ement primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null,
>   `email` varchar(255) not n     ull, `password` varchar(255) not null,
>   `remember_token` varchar(100) null,      `created_at` timestamp null,
>   `updated_at` timestamp null) default character      set utf8mb4
>   collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
>
> In Connection.php line 449:
>                                                                                     SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users'
>   alre     ady exists

```
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$ php artisan migrate:rollback
Nothing to rollback.
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.8.17 (PHP 7.1.20-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> Schema::drop('users')
=> null
>>> Schema::drop('password_resets')
=> null
>>> Schema::drop('orders')
=> null
>>> exit
Exit:  Goodbye.
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$ php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrating: 2018_08_18_071213_create_orders_table
Migrated:  2018_08_18_071213_create_orders_table
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$
```

Also define the method `down()`, if it doesn't exist. 
Otherwise, it'll show

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'XYZ.ABC' (SQL: drop table `ABC`)

```
/**
  * Reverse the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('ABC');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i just had to delete a row from my migrations table and then execute

> php artisan migrate --path=app/foo/migrations/2014_01_21_143531_create_teams_table.php