# php artisan make:auth scaffolding not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to activate the authentication in Laravel 5.7. Reading the documentation I have started a new fresh project with the command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel bpcb
```

and then I have edited my `.env` file with my credentials:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=valcanale
DB_USERNAME=stefano
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

after that I wrote the command `php artisan migrate` but I've got the message

`Nothing to migrate`

Under `app\Http\Controllers\Auth` I have these files:

```
ForgotPasswordController.php
LoginController.php
RegisterController.php
ResetPasswordController.php
VerificationPasswordController.php
```

This is a fresh project and I haven't touched anything. Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: first you need to execute this `php artisan make:auth`

Comment: Ok i execute the command, but still Nothing to migrate

Comment: What's under your `database\migrations`?

Comment: I have the two default migrations but the date of migration is 2014_10_12. The files are 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php           2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you try this( Also make sure your `.env` database settings are correct )

```
 php artisan config:cache
 php artisan migrate:reset
 php artisan migrate
```

After this check your database

Got it from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266956/laravels-artisan-says-nothing-to-migrate).

Comment: Tested but always Nothing to migrate

Comment: It works! Now in my db i can see 2 new tables called `users` and `passwrd_resets` thank you!:)

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that your .env settings are correct.
Then restart the server ( stop and then type php artisan serve again )
Then run command `php artisan make:auth` 
after this  run `php artisan migrate` ( run migrate command after making auth )