# Laravel's php artisan migrate --path='path' works but doesn't work when specifying php artisan migrate

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-migrations

So as mentioned in the subject, the migration works if I run the files seperately, i.e.:

```
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (1,140.26ms)

....
```

But doesn't seem to work without the path option as shown in the code below:

```
php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.
Nothing to migrate.
```

I've already referred to this link [Laravel's Artisan says nothing to migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266956/laravels-artisan-says-nothing-to-migrate) and a couple others to no avail.

Comment: Is there anything to migrate? What does `php artisan migrate:status` show?

Comment: Yes there is, as it's just after I've created a new empty database.
So it should create the `failed_jobs`, `password_resets` and `users` tables.  All it does when running `php artisan migrate` is it creates the `migrations` table within the database.
The result of running `php artisan migrate:status` is "No migrations found".

Comment: Would `php artisan migrate:fresh` install any migrations? Never had that happen before.

Comment: I tried `php artisan migrate:fresh` too with no success.
Yeah it's very frustrating as if I'm not mistaken this has been happening since laravel 5.x so haven't used the `migration` artisan commands much and rather stuck to creating the database and tables via a database script...

Comment: run  `composer dump-autoload` and try again.

Comment: Thanks still getting the same result after running `composer dump-autoload` and then running `php artisan migrate`:
Migration table created successfully.
Nothing to migrate.

Comment: i followed this step, it worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/65950045/12015288 . You just have to look at the migrations table in the database, delete 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table table row

Comment: @afrizal Thanks, however there's no delete 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table row in the migrations table for me. So unfortunately this doesn't work in my case.